# Fancybox gem rails 5.1

Tags: fancybox-2, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-5.1, fancybox-3

Currently, it seems that for Rails 5.1 we do not have any compatible Fancybox gem Latest Fancybox3 is compatible with rails 5.0 but not 5.1 (https://github.com/fobiasmog/fancybox3/issues/3) .

I am upgrading my application from Rails 4.2.7 version to Rails 5.1.4, I need help to figure out an alternate for Fancybox.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just curious, would it not be easier to use without the gem?

Comment: I tried, but the behavior is not as expected and that may be because of  Rails 5.1 drop jQuery as a dependency. I am not sure if I am in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried adding jQuery? https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/06/20/rails-5-1-has-dropped-dependency-on-jquery-from-the-default-stack.html